# Font style file size is too much in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fonts

After building apk of a project in android studio, I analyzed the apk file by going to the toolbar above,clicked Build->Analyze and then select the apk file.

I got the info that the raw file size of the app is 5.5 MB. Of them,in the assets folder,a single font file was taking 5 MB.How do I compress the size of this font file and thereby optimise the overall memory footprint of the app?

Thank you for your time.

Note.The font file name is msmincho.ttf

Comment: I would not consider 5 MB to be large at all. The only proper way that I can see to reduce the apk size of your apk file would be reducing the size of the font file.

Comment: @Goran How should i reduce the size of the font file and include in the assets/fonts/ folder?

Comment: unfortunately I cannot help you with that one. Only thing that comes to my mind right now is removing unnecesary characters, if any.
You probably should not worry about it and continue writing your app.

Comment: If you are that worried about your apk size then why are you using custom font? For most android apps custom font is not a good idea.

Comment: @Okas i know.And the text size is only of 6 characters.But it has to be this custom font.That is the client's order.What to do :)

Comment: Easy - if the client insist on using this font then he has to live with larger apk.

Comment: @Okas ok I got your point.Thanks for your time.But is there really no way of  compressing the font file?:0

Comment: Font file is already compressed. As Goran said only way is to create custom font file with only some glyphs. Not that I recommend this approach. :)

Comment: Your ttf file for 6 characters is 5mb? Then your ttf must contain images rather then a vector. Ask your client to provide you a ttf file that uses vectors. This will greatly reduce the size of ttf file.

Comment: @Goran Actually the letters are PORTAL.I have to put this custom font styled.I am actually talking about this word's 6 characters.